# Fail to execute org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce: org/codehaus/plexus/util/StringUtils

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jhipster, maven-enforcer-plugin

**Execution enforce-versions of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce: org/codehaus/plexus/util/StringUtils using jhipster 4.3.0**

```
Pom.xml configuration 


    <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
    <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-versions</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <message>You are running an older version of Maven. JHipster requires at least Maven ${maven.version}</message>
                                <version>[${maven.version},)</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <message>You are running an older version of Java. JHipster requires at least JDK ${java.version}</message>
                                <version>[${java.version}.0,)</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

**While running mvn clean install the following error is comming :**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ testproject ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\admin\git\testproject\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ thepellestore ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 34 resources
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ thepellestore ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 44 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ thepellestore ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.477 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-16T13:38:03+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/346M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) on project thepellestore: Execution enforce-versions of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce: org/codehaus/plexus/util/StringUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/1.4.1/maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/commons-lang-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/enforcer/enforcer-api/1.4.1/enforcer-api-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/enforcer/enforcer-rules/1.4.1/enforcer-rules-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.3/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.4/plexus-io-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.StringUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: Which version of Maven are you running?

Comment: What does print `mvnw enforcer:display-info`? Maybe you're running JDK 9 which is not supported by JHipster

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using maven 3.5.2

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I got this error :
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:display-info (default-cli) @ testproject ---
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.5.0
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:display-info : Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:display-info failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:display-info: org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtilsorg.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I am using JDK 8

Comment: OK, so probably something got corrupted in your local maven repository, you could try to delete `C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository` and then re-run mvnw

Comment: ok will try this

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the specified versions of maven and java.
Maven required version is to be 3.6.3 or "greater" and java version should be greater than 1.8.